# iPhone resizing HTML emails

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm building HTML responsive emails and everything looks good, except iPhone/iOS Mail app. It renders my email with some kind of zoom out, seems like it's rendering as desktop. But this only happens if I copy/paste my rendered HTML (get the HTML, save it, open in browser, select everything and copy) in an email client like Gmail. If I get that same HTML code and send through an email client that supports HTML stuff, everything looks good.

Some things I've already tried:

- ```html
  <body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
  ```
- ```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, 
  minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  ```
- Removing `table-layout: fixed;`

HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
>
  <head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG />
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
      table,
      td {
        color: #000000;
      }
      @media only screen and (min-width: 520px) {
        .row {
          width: 500px !important;
        }
        .row .col {
          vertical-align: top;
        }

        .row .col-100 {
          width: 500px !important;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 520px) {
        .row-container {
          max-width: 100% !important;
          padding-left: 0px !important;
          padding-right: 0px !important;
        }
        .row .col {
          min-width: 320px !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        .row {
          width: calc(100% - 40px) !important;
        }
        .col {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .col > div {
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      table,
      tr,
      td {
        vertical-align: top;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .ie-container table,
      .mso-container table {
        table-layout: fixed;
      }

      * {
        line-height: inherit;
      }

      a[x-apple-data-detectors='true'] {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body
    class="clean-body"
    style="
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #000000;
    "
  >
    <!--[if IE]><div class="ie-container"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]><div class="mso-container"><![endif]-->
    <table
      style="
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-spacing: 0;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        vertical-align: top;
        min-width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
      "
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top">
          <td
            style="
              word-break: break-word;
              border-collapse: collapse !important;
              vertical-align: top;
            "
          >
            <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;"><![endif]-->

            <div
              class="row-container"
              style="padding: 0px; background-color: transparent"
            >
              <div
                class="row"
                style="
                  margin: 0 auto;
                  min-width: 320px;
                  max-width: 500px;
                  overflow-wrap: break-word;
                  word-wrap: break-word;
                  word-break: break-word;
                  background-color: transparent;
                "
              >
                <div
                  style="
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    display: table;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: transparent;
                  "
                >
                  <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding: 0px;background-color: transparent;" align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:500px;"><tr style="background-color: transparent;"><![endif]-->

                  <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="500" style="width: 500px;padding: 0px;border-top: 0px solid transparent;border-left: 0px solid transparent;border-right: 0px solid transparent;border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
                  <div
                    class="col col-100"
                    style="
                      max-width: 320px;
                      min-width: 500px;
                      display: table-cell;
                      vertical-align: top;
                    "
                  >
                    <div style="width: 100% !important">
                      <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div
                        style="
                          padding: 0px;
                          border-top: 0px solid transparent;
                          border-left: 0px solid transparent;
                          border-right: 0px solid transparent;
                          border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
                        "
                      ><!--<![endif]-->
                        <table
                          style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif"
                          role="presentation"
                          cellpadding="0"
                          cellspacing="0"
                          width="100%"
                          border="0"
                        >
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td
                                style="
                                  overflow-wrap: break-word;
                                  word-break: break-word;
                                  padding: 10px;
                                  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                                "
                                align="left"
                              >
                                <div
                                  style="
                                    line-height: 140%;
                                    text-align: left;
                                    word-wrap: break-word;
                                  "
                                >
                                  <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 140%">
                                    <span
                                      style="
                                        font-size: 18px;
                                        line-height: 25.2px;
                                      "
                                      >Prescribing information for XIRION ▼ and
                                      adverse event reporting details can be
                                      found here</span
                                    >
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                      </div>
                      <!--<![endif]-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td><![endif]-->
                  <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso]></div><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]></div><![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you selecting everything from a browser window anyway, when you have the actual HTML code. HTML should always be dropped into an ESP and sent that way, which as you've already mentions, works fine.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein my customers send those emails. The thing is: there are a lot of tutorials teaching to send HTML emails in that way (selecting everything). Probably this is leading a lot of them sending in a wrong way. I just wanted to make sure if something could be done to fix that.

Comment: I know email signatures are recommended to be saved down in this way, but not email templates. I've never seen a tutorial mention this method of saving but I'm also not doubting that you have seen some.

Comment: Overall, I would highly advise against saving templates/copying the contents for send. You don't know how much of the original code is actually being copied. For all you know, it is only copying the visual elements and not copying your media queries etc. Always copy & paste your HTML code and paste into your ESP of choice.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein do you have some useful links talking about that? "I know email signatures are recommended to be saved down in this way, but not email templates"

Comment: Talking about how to use HTML email templates? I think the main issue you have is pasting HTML or the copied artwork from a browser into email clients like Gmail which aren't exactly built for that type of use. You should be using an actual ESP like Mailchimp, Klaviyo, Drip, Campaign Monitor etc to send fully mobile responsive email templates.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein yes. I'm searching for some links that could be sent to users to influence them that pasting HTML is a wrong way to send that kind of email.

Comment: Oh, you probably aren't going to find anything like that as I've never actually seen it recommended that you copy and paste the design from browser. Industry tutorials and recommendations are always to paste the raw code into a platform, full stop.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein yeah, they do say that HTML isn't supported by Gmail for example, but they show copy/paste as a workaround for that. Like [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-send-html-email-3468764)

Comment: Oh god, no... Please don't allow people to do this. If you want to send HTML email, then you need to use an ESP. Gmail is going to process that HTML any way it likes so anyone using these methods cannot expect anything to pull across correctly.